# What is this low-growing leafy plant that looks like salad greens?

Tags: identification, leaf-vegetables

This is something I planted in my garden and forgot about whether it was a salad green or something else. I'd like to know what it is and if it's edible.

[image]

Comment: does it have a milky sap when you break a leaf?

Comment: No it doesn't have a milky sap

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a [Mustard Green](http://www.harvesttotable.com/2008/02/mustard_greensmustard_greens_c/). Yummm. It's edible. Good habit to always ask before tasting, eating...